# Serial Correlation in Rolling Change Linear Regression Models

Tags: time-series, regression, auto-correlation

1.) Lets say I have two time series GDP, BUSINV from (1948, 2019); Frequency of Data is Quarterly.

2.) Say I want to predict GDP i.e. GDP ~ BUSINV

3.) Since GDP is not stationary (i.e. level) and its not conceptually sound to forecast level of a metric like GDP, I would take the difference (i.e. returns)

4.) Say I create two  models

4.a) pchGDP(QoQ) ~ pchBUSINV (QoQ)

4.b) pchGDP(5Y) ~ pchBUSINV(5Y), note this is a rolling change series, implying we are introducing serial auto-correlation. pch is percent change.

5.) the Adj RSQ for QoQ model is say 60% due to quarterly noise. While the Adj RSQ 5Y model is 95% due to smoothing effect of rolling change. The second model despite the good fit fails the serial Auto - Correlation test.

What is the best way to deal with this problem?

1.) Use the QoQ Model

2.) Use the 5Y Model ignore the serial correlation in residuals (if QoQ model doesn't also exhibit serial correlation)

3.) Should I be performing Serial Auto Correlation test on residuals after converting them to quarterly residuals for the 5Y % change Model i.e. QuarterlyResiduals = residual - lag(residual,1), and then CheckSerialCorrelation (QuarterlyResiduals ).

4.) Any other options?